# How to prepare data to analyze two values simultaneously as one

Tags: categorical-data, data-transformation

as a newbie in statistics I'm having trouble with preparing my data.

I have data where a measure is performed on left and right side. When comparing group means I need to take simultaneously both measurement from left and right.
So for example I have:

Case     Side_left    SIde_right

When analyzing means should be n=2xCases, so if I have 15 cases, my means is computed from 30 measurements, 15 from left and 15 from right.

Simply creating averaged from left and right won't do the trick, because  SD's are different, Also if I have missing value from one side, for 15 cases I'd have 29 measurements. By creating means first this information is omited. Is there a way to do it SPSS or any other software or manual solution.

Comment: It might help a little if you provide some context by saying what you intend to do with this measure next. I can see a few different ways you could go with this, but they may not all be appropriate to your goal.

Comment: After descriptive statistics and exploring differences I'd analyze for correlations and prediction (regression).

Comment: Okay, and another couple of questions: 1) Are these measures your independent or dependent variables, and 2) Do you expect the right and left measures to be related (and if so, how)?

Comment: These are the independent variables.

Comment: They are related in a such a way that they represent the same measurement, but on alternative side - nerve conduction studies for left and right nerve. Their are expected to be close to each other, as a value, but sometimes that's not the case. SOmetimes a value would be removed, or would be intentionally omited, if for example there is trauma of the right nerve, we just don't take it into account, even if we have measured it.

Answer (score 0):

I can see three possible approaches for dealing with this.

**1. The "just focus on one side" approach**

If you believe that the two measures are really closely related, and can produce a reasonably high correlation coefficient to back this up, then you could use data from only one side (whichever side has the least missing data).

I've done work in the past using eye-tracking where we only analyse movements with the right eye (right tends to be the dominant one). For most of the phenomena I've studied, I've had no reason to believe that the left eye will do anything substantively different, so I don't analyse that data (in reality, I don't collect it... Binocular eye-tracking is a hassle!)

**2. The "just take an average and live with some missing data" approach**

This is relatively similar to the first approach really. If you don't think the two sides are going to be all that different then just average them. Yes, the averaging will add a little noise, but if the effect you're interested in is robust enough then it probably won't make a difference.

**3. The "take a sledgehammer to crack a nut" approach**

Use PCA/FA to reduce the two sides, which we believe are going to be very closely related, to a single score. This score will probably not be on the same scale as the raw measurements, so you lose some interpretability.

As with 2, you'll lose some cases where there's missing data, but, really, I'm not sure there's an approach out there (short of imputation) where you won't suffer this problem.

Personally, as long as the correlation coefficient was good then I'd probably just do 1.

Comment: Actually the second route is prefered in most papers, and I already done the analyzis that way, but I'm feeling I'm missing data. ALthough not all explain in details how they collected the data (only one side, both sides) and how exactly they computed it. Sometimes there are bigger than expected differences.  Here is one paper that make it the way I want, but I really can't figure out how they prepared the dataset: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2777171/

Comment: How much data are you losing due to averaging? If averaging is the default approach in your field then you should probably go that way (it's one less potential hurdle for you to face when you try to publish this).

Comment: Have you considered asking others in your field how exactly they do it? If people are reporting their work without sufficient detail for you to repeat it then I don't think it unreasonable for you to ask them to give you relevant information.

Comment: I've asked, they haven't done in the way I need it or stil don't have answer.

Comment: I'm not really sure I know what to suggest. I'm finding it difficult to reconcile the one position that averaging the two measures is the norm, with the other position that you don't know how they're doing it. If you don't know how they're doing it, then how do you know they're averaging? I don't know this field though, so my general advice would be that if there's a convention to do it one way then do that unless it doesn't make sense for you (e.g. because you're having to delete more data than everyone else). If the convention doesn't work, then come up with your own defensible approach.

Comment: Sure, I could it manually.