# Statistics on paired eyes

Tags: paired-comparisons, paired-data

I wish to examine the correlation between two variables ($A$ & $B$) of the eye. Each participant (e.g. $100$ participants) contributes two eyes ($200$ samples). I don't wish to look at the relationship of $A$ & $B$ for right eye, and for left eye individually, but just for the relationship of $A$ & $B$ for all eyes.

- Do I disregard left and right, and that they are from the same participant and take $N=200$?
- Do I randomly select a single eye from each participant ($N=100$)?
  Or is there a way of using both eyes taking into consideration that there are $100$ pairs of highly correlated data?

Comment: What kind of variables are these?  That would seem to matter; for instance, if their difference is meaningful, why not examine (say) the difference between the left eye and right eye?  But if the difference is not meaningful, or its meaning depends on the values in the individual eyes, then another approach would be required.

Comment: You may want to look at this question, and the answer I gave, which appears relatively similar: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/224715/29532

Comment: Thank you for your reply! They are continuous variables. Ok, let's just say I am looking at the correlation between the length of the eyeball vs the thickness of the lens in the eye. I have data for 200 eyes (100 right, 100 left) from 100 subjects. Right and left data for all variables are highly correlated.

Comment: is GEE appropriate?